# how to pass 'meta' in a loop in scrapy

Tags: scrapy, request

```
def district_parse(self,response):
    item2 = response.meta["item"]
    Data2 = json.loads(re.findall(r'[(](.*?)[)]', response.text)[0])
    detail2 = Data2['data']['list']
    for loop1 in detail2:
        item2["district_time"] = loop1["timeHuman"]
        item2["district_name"] = loop1["district_name"]
        item2["district_congest"] = loop1["index"]
        item2["district_speed"] = loop1["speed"]
        item2["district_length"] = loop1["length"]

        url = "https://www.example.com"
        yield Request(url, meta={"item2": copy.deepcopy(item2)}, callback=self.curvehistory_parse)
```

'detail2' is a list containing multiple dictionaries. I want to pass multiple dictionaries as parameters to ‘meta‘ in turn, but only the first dictionary can always be passed in.How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new method after district_parse, called 'parse_details' which will do the yield to output file.
2. add a callback in district_parse, eg callback=self.parse_details
   and pass the meta dict to the new method  one at a time to yield your output from the 'parse_details' method.